# Why seq-scan can be much faster than index-scan and index-only-scan in this simple query?

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-performance

I am using `PostgreSQL 9.4.4`. I have a query like this:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM A,B WHERE A.a = B.b
```

a and b are the Primary Keys of tables A and  B, so there are B-indexes on a & b

By default, PostgreSQL will use seq-scan on AB and use hash join, I force it to do the index-scan and index-only-scan.

The result showed that, seq scan is much faster than the other two, it takes more time to do the full scan on a,b for index-scan and index-only-scan.

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT COUNT(*) FROM journal,paper WHERE journal.paper_id = paper.paper_id;

[image]

Can someone explain it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW the size of the two tables are not small, at least 5k tuples

Comment: 5k **is** small

Comment: Post the output of `explain (analyze, buffers, verbose)` for both executions

Comment: I post the explain result, hope for your answer, thank you so much !

Comment: Gah, screenshot? I can work with it, but in future *please* just post the text. It's searchable that way, and easier to reformat, read, paste to explain.depesz.com, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know the reason now.

I need to vacuum the tables before using index-only-scan, otherwise, if a sufficiently high number of heap pages where modified since the last vacuum, the planner will not choose to use index-only scan.  When only a small amount of pages have been changed, an index-only scan may happen, which then involves heap fetches.

If I force it to use index-only-scan, it will fetch data from table for each tuple scanned, which can cause great cost.

Comment: @dezso I know the index-only-scan is designed to not fetch data from heaps.  In my experiments, I let index-only-scan be the only one on (turn off seq-scan and index-scan), then I explain analyze my query, it shows that it indeed use index-only-scan, but the heap fetches is quite high, equal to the number of tuples in scanned table.

Comment: @dezso However, after i vacuum all tables involved in the query, the heap fetches become zero, which means index-only-scan doesn't touch heaps this time.  So we can draw the conclusion, index-only-scan will still try to fetch data from table in some case, it depends on the visibility map, when u  vacuum your tables, the visibility map is set to visible to all users  which can result in best performance of index-only-scan.

Comment: maybe u need do experiments to verify your thoughts, use "explain analyze verbose YOUR QUERY"

Comment: @ChrisTien an index only scan does not touch the table.

Comment: Hm, now I found [an excellent post from Robert Haas](http://rhaas.blogspot.de/2010/11/index-only-scans.html), where he describes these in detail.  I have to admit you are right - index-only scans are not always index-only, but they try as long as it is possible.  At the same time, an index-only scan with additional heap fetches is possible when a sufficient portion of the table pages remains unchanged since the last vacuum.

Comment: @ypercube if the index-only-scan does not touch heaps then why there are lines under index-only-scan said "heap fetches: XXXX(number of tuples of the scanned table)"  in the result of Explain Analyze Query ?

Comment: I can't so you are probably right. It's either a bug or they are not entirely correct in the documentation and index-only scans can (or have to) in some cases use the table instead of the visibility map (or both).

Comment: @ypercube *an index-only scan does not touch the table*. False. It *might not* touch the table, but only if the visibility map shows that all  heap pages are 100% visible for the scanned index leaves.

Comment: @CraigRinger thnx for clarifying this.

Answer (score 5):

This is quite a common query (pardon the pun! :-) ) from people running queries which perform full table scans (FTS), when the poster feels that the system should make use of the index(es).

Basically, it boils down to the explanation given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5255988/470530). If the tables are so small, the optimiser will say that "it's not worth the bother of going to the index, doing a lookup and then fetching the data, instead, I'll just slurp in all the data and pick out what I need", i.e. perform an FTS.

[EDIT in answer to @txsing's comment]

For an MVCC ([multi-version concurrency control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control)) database, you have to traverse every record for a count at a given moment - that's why, for example, a COUNT(*) is much more expensive for MySQL's InnoDB rather than MyISAM.

An excellent explantion (for PostgreSQL) is available [here](http://rhaas.blogspot.de/2010/11/index-only-scans.html). The guy who wrote this post is a "[major contributor](http://www.postgresql.org/community/contributors/)" to PostgreSQL (thanks to @dezso for leading me to that post).

Comment: since it is COUNT(*) in select clause, so there is no need to fetch data from the table, right? so I think index-only-scan should be the fastest one, but the result is not :-(

Comment: @ChrisTien An index-only scan should usually be fastest for a simple count, if the visibility map is up to date so not many heap pages have to be fetched. This is *not* a simple count though, there's a join involved.