# Columns names are case sensitive on postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4, case-sensitive

I have successfully migrated database from MySQL to PostgreSQL. While I am trying to connect with `ofbiz`, I am getting an error saying that

> "user_id" not found.

When I query against postgres by using

```
select * from user where user_id='1';
```

It's throwing the same error. But when I try with

```
select * from user where "USER_ID"='1';
```

It's fetching correctly. Table names are not case sensitive here, only column names. Can anyone give me a solution please?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Answer (score 2):

When migrating, did the migration script double-quote the column names when creating tables? That would preserve the case.

You could either fix the migration script and re-import, or rename the columns e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE my_user RENAME COLUMN "USER_ID" TO user_id;
```

(note: `user` was used in the original question but that's a reserved keyword in Postgres so that couldn't have been one of the tables involved)

Comment: That's an unfortunate example because `user` is a reserved word ;)

Comment: @CraigRinger indeed, was using the table name that the questioner asked. Should probably edit it!

Comment: @CraigRinger can you throw some light into this conversation? http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/108129/why-seq-scan-can-be-much-faster-than-index-scan-and-index-only-scan-in-this-simp/108926?noredirect=1#comment198731_108926

Comment: Craig, I am facing this issue for all the tables. The table user is an example one not an exact table which i am using.As per your suggestion let me verify the migration script first.

Comment: Hi, This issue is because of character set. In my Mysql db character set is latin1 and collations are latin1_swedish_ci and latin1_general_cs. previously i have tried with utf8 encoding.Thats why case sensitive issue i hope. But now i tried with latin1, mysql dump and conversion got success but while restoring dump into postgres its throwing an error like psql:dbname.psql:14: ERROR:  collation "latin1_general_cs" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist. can anyone give me a solution plz?

Comment: Also i am getting the following error. dbname.psql:909: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x96